# Adding a small/negligible two-tone border to bottom of slides in Beamer style

Tags: beamer, formatting, header-footer

All,

I'd like some help making some minor cosmetic changes to my `beamer` template. I like the template I have no since it's rather bare/plain (which is how I like it), but I'd like to add a little color to it in the form of a small/negligible two-tone border at the bottom of the slides.

Right now, I have something like this

[image]

and would like something like this, even if it means adding just a little padding to the `footline` to separate it from the two-tone border.

[image]

Right now, I have the following `footline` style in my template.

```
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{my footline}
{
\ifnum \insertpagenumber=1
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=.8ex,dp=1ex,center]{}%
  % empty environment to raise height
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
\else
\hspace*{.5cm}\Tiny{%
\hspace*{50pt} \hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{.00cm} \\ \vspace*{5pt}}%
\fi
}
```

Basically, I keep the title frame plain and have those page numbers on every other slide. I'd like to keep it like that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. `beamer` markup still isn't very intuitive to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very quick solution is to just add `\rule{width}{height}` in the desired colour:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{my footline}{%
    \ifnum\insertpagenumber=1
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=.8ex,dp=1ex,center]{}%
            % empty environment to raise height
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
    \vskip0pt%
    \else%
        {%
            \Tiny
            \hfill%
            \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber \hspace*{0.1cm}%
            \newline%
            \textcolor{red}{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4mm}}\newline%
            \textcolor{black}{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.5mm}}%
        }%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}

    \frame{a}
    \frame{d}
    \frame{c}       
    \frame{b}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It took some additional tweaking to get exactly what I wanted, but this was great. Thanks!

Comment: `\color` *doesn't* have a second mandatory argument; either use `\textcolor{red}{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4mm}}` or `{\color{red}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4mm}}` (+1, by the way).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for pointing this out, I modified my example accordingly.